# application.js in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where am I supposed to create the application.js file in rails. Inside javascripts directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It has to be in the javascripts folder

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.1 changes this behavior to the app/assets folder, and it is a special manifest file, not code.